# What to use to add a series of integers in a arrayList from user input

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io, bufferedreader

I am working on a Server Client program in Java, using Sockets.

I ask the user to input a series of integers, add them in an `ArrayList` and send them over to the server as an Object using `ObjectOutputStream`. The Server then receives the object.

I parse the object as an `ArrayList` and then I use a method to calculate what is the maximum number of the integers and return it as a string to the client.

I am using `BufferedReader` for the user input

In a sense what I need is a logic on how to:

To check for the users input, if it is not "`Ok`" or press `Enter`

The user should be able to add numbers separated by a **space**.

If then he presses Enter then should exit the loop and the numbers add at the array

I have so far:

```
 BufferedReader integers = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        //  send int 1, for the Max number option
                        pw.println(option);
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                        String x = integers.readLine();
                        if(integers!=null){

                            readInt(integers);

                    }


                        objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                        objectOut.writeObject(maxNum);
                        objectOut.flush();
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                        objectOut.close();
                        break;
```

The readIn method:

```
public static int readInt(BufferedReader stdIn) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String line = stdIn.readLine();
                int value = Integer.parseInt(line);
                return value;
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                ;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with using ArrayList?

Comment: There is not problem withe the ArrayList, my problem how to use logic. I need the user to add the numbers in one line, and then if he press ok, the number to get added in the arrayList. I am stack in the logic really. Don't know even when to start, I have tried since yesterday but nothing seems to be working

Comment: So, user is entering 1, 2 and 3 like: - 123?? or all in new line?? 1,enter, 2, enter, 3, enter??

Comment: Yea either that or 1 and then press ok, then add another one and so on. Until maybe he presses send or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better handle this with `Scanner`. `BufferedReader` is quite old and deprecated.

```
List<Integer> seriesOfInt = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    seriesOfInt.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Or, if user is entering all those numbers in one line with some delimiter between them, say a whitespace (), you can split the input and store in ArrayList..

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    List<String> seriesOfIntString = Arrays.asList(scanner.next().split(" "));
}
```

Comment: @user1710035.. See my first solution.. That will solve your problem.. It will take user input, till he enters a `int`..

Comment: Thanx allot, I was thinking about the `Scanner`, but I keep also seeing the `BufferedReader`everywhere?

Comment: @user1710035.. You should  not use `BufferedReader` any more for user input.. It is deprecated..

Comment: In your first solution, how do I break the look. By pressing enter?

Comment: @user1710035.. It will automatically get break, the moment user enters a blank line.. i.e presses an `enter` without inputting an integer..

Comment: @user1710035.. Yeah by pressing enter.. Didn't see that last line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for something like [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?
With this method you can split the input by any character, in your case `" "`
It will return a string array, which you can then add to your ArrayList.